# PHP CSS how to add some style to existing style

Tags: php, css

I have this scenario in a PHP file:

```
<input type="text" id="myinput" minlength="6" maxlength="6" value="..." onkeyup="..." onfocusout="..." style="width: 20%; display: inline;" />
```

where I'd like to add some css if I got an error... I tried first with :

```
<input type="text" id="myinput" minlength="6" maxlength="6" value="..." onkeyup="..." onfocusout="..." style="width: 20%; display: inline;" <?php if($this->error == "2"){ echo 'style="border:2px solid red;"'; } ?> />
```

but it didn't applied because there is already a CSS... then I tried calling

```
?><script>$("#myinput").addClass('k3_border_ko');</script><?php
```

in the place of code where I encounter an error on that input but it didn't applied...

How I can apply adding that border color red if I have already a style in this way?

Thanks in advance!
Cheers! :-)

Comment: You are `echo`ing the new style outwith the quotes in the given HTML input element. Put the `echo` command within the `style="blah=blah;<?php echo ...?>"` etc - You do not need to add a new `style` attribute

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius , thank you very much! it worked! didn't thought I could just echo css inside style itself!..

Answer (score 0):

a simple approach would be

```
$style_noerr = '...';
$style_err = '...';

<input ... <?php if($this->error == "2"){ echo $style_err; } else {echo $style_noerr ;} ?> />
```

irrelevant note: your input has no *name* field but you'll need.